# What is the PDF of $X_1X_2-X_3X_4$ conditionally on $\sum\limits_{k=1}^4X_k=1$, for $(X_k)$ i.i.d. uniform on $[0,1]$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Consider the following expression

$$D=X-(X+Y)(X+Z) \ \ \text{under the constraint} \ \ X+Y+Z \leq 1 \tag{1}$$

(being understood that $X, Y$ and $Z$ are $\geq 0$).

This expression can also be written under the form :

$$D=XT-YZ=\begin{vmatrix}X&Y\\Z&T\end{vmatrix} \ \text{given that} \ X+Y+Z+T=1.\tag{2}$$

where $(X,Y,Z,T)$ take their values in $[0,1]^4$ ($[0,1]$ being the set of **real** values between $0$ and $1$).

(all these constraints are due to the fact that we deal with a complete system of events ; see "Origin of the question" below with definitions (4)).

```
My question : what is the pdf (probability density function) of random variable D ?
```

**My work :**

I have attempted different computations, but they have failed to be conclusive ; I hit on the difficulty to assign a distribution to the random vector $(X,Y,Z,T)$ taking into account constraint $X+Y+Z+T=1$. I have in particular attempted to replace uniformly distributed $X,Y,Z,T$ on $\mathbb{R}$ by random variables taking discrete values $\{0/n,1/n,\cdots (n-1)/n,1\}$ without success.

I have made simulations displaying a rather "smooth" symmetrical behavior (see Fig. below displaying an histogram for a large number of simulations) with a relative spike around value $d=0$.

[image]

**The origin of this question :** A recent question about extreme values of what could be called a "degree of dependence':

$$D=P(A \cap B) - P(A)P(B) \tag{3}$$

(that can be transformed into (1)) and the answer I gave : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3090278
has triggered (as often is the case) a different question : instead of restricting our attention to the extreme values of (1) (or the equivalent expression (2)), I asked myself the more general question of the pdf  of the values taken by (1) with the following definitions :

$$X=P(A \cap B), \ Y=P(A \cap B^c), \ Z=P(A^c \cap B), \ T=P(A^c \cap B^c).\tag{4}$$

as one can see globally on the following diagram :

[image]

Besides, if one drops constraint $X+Y+Z+T=1$ (yielding a very different issue), what would become the pdf of $D$ ?(I give below a histogram gathering results of simulation with this hypothesis).

[image]

Comment: First, note that you can eliminate the condition by doing a few operations on the determinant to transform it into: $D=X-(X+Y)(X+Z)$. (Just add the first column to the last column and then the first row to the last row.) So that's already one less constraint.

Comment: Then the condition $D\leq d$ determines a section of space bounded by a hyperboloid. Adding the conditions that $X,Y,Z \in [0,1]$ means that you have to find the volume of that section of space within the unit cube to find the probability.

Comment: @Raskolnikov In fact expression $D=X-(X+Y)(X+Z)=P(A \cap B)-P(A)P(B)$ is the initial expression ... and you are right that, although less symmetrical, this expression avoids to use constraint (2).

Comment: @Raskolnikov ... but it will remain the constraint $X+Y+Z \leq 1$.

Comment: @Raskolnikov I have slightly modified my first sentences in order to take into account your remarks.

Comment: Thanks @Did for rewriting the title very explicitly in particular with "i.i..d. uniform on [0,1]"